# Primes in the support appear in prime chains?

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> Let $M$ be a finitely generated module over a Noetherian ring $A$. Suppose that $p\subseteq A$ is a prime ideal which is contained in the support of $M$, i.e., $M_p\neq 0$. Then does there always exist a prime chain of $M$, i.e., a finite sequence of the form $M_0(=0)\subseteq M_1\subseteq \dots \subseteq M_n(=M)$ where each successive quotient is isomorphic to $A/p_i$ for some prime ideal $p_i\subseteq A$, such that $p=p_j$ for some $j$?

As for motivation, if $M_0(=0)⊆M_1⊆\cdots⊆M_n(=M)$ is a prime chain of $M$ with primes $\{p_1,...,p_n\}$, then each $p_i$ is contained in the support of $M$. So I was wondering if every prime which is in the support of $M$ appears in some prime chain of $M$? Of course, with the support being not finite (usually), we cannot expect all of them to appear in any particular prime chain. But at least, for each one can we find a prime chain where it appears?

Answer (score 2):

OK, got it. If $p$ is a prime in the support of $M$, then the annihilator of $M/pM$ is $p$. Since $p$ is associated to $M/pM$, there exists $pM\subset M_1\subseteq M$ such that $M_1/pM\cong A/p$. Now take prime chains of $M/M_1$ and $pM$. Together, we get a prime chain of $M$ where $p$ appears as one of the primes.

Comment: If $M,N$ are finitely generated modules over a ring $A$ then $\text{Ann }(M)+\text{Ann }(N) \subseteq \text{Ann }(M\otimes N) \subseteq \sqrt{\text{Ann }(M)+\text{Ann }(N)}$. The first inclusion is obvious, and the second one is an exercise in localization and Nakayama's lemma. Now take $N:=A/p$. As for the down-votes, i'm fine with them. If someone finds a question dull, i expect him/her to either ignore it or ask the questioner about the motivation before   concluding that the question/questioner (or both!) is stupid and down-voting! But if someone wishes to do so, it's not my problem.

Comment: I have a simpler argument about $Ann(M/pM)=p$: if $a(M/pM)=0$ then $aM\subseteq pM$ and thus $aM_p\subseteq pM_p$. Suppose that $a\notin p$. Then $a$ is invertible in $A_p$ and therefore $aM_p=M_p$. Now Nakayama tells us that $M_p=0$, a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks for your short argument! Actually, i knew the general result and blithely applied it without bothering to give a second thought.